# Deleting an array created by a function

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm making a tool to solve [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHh0ui5mi_E) although I got massively sidetracked by the code itself.

In various places I have functions that return (pointers to) arrays. Most times those functions are recursive and the array created in the inner call may be useless later.

I tried to use `delete[]`; even though the compiler didn't complain and the program ran fine I could see that a huge ammount of memory was being allocated.
The code looked something like this:

```
template <typename Type> Type* foo(unsigned short size,...)
{
    //...
    Type *tmp;
    //...
    tmp=foo(param,...);
    //...
    delete[] tmp;
    //...
}
```

I then asked myself if, when the array was created out of scope, `delete[]` actually deleted all the allocated memory or just the first index (or nothing at all?).

I rewrote that piece of code to look like this:

```
template <typename Type> Type* foo(unsigned short size,...)
{
    //...
    Type *tmp;
    //..
    tmp = new Type[i];
    tmp = foo(param,...);
    //...
    delete[] tmp;
    //...
}
```

Memory consumption lowered, however I quickly realized that the array I created just before calling `foo(...)` wasn't actually deleted... ever.

So lastly I tried:

```
template <typename Type> Type* foo(unsigned short size,...)
{
    //...
    Type *tmp, *dump;
    //..
    dump = tmp = new Type[i];
    tmp = foo(param,...);
    delete[] dump;
    //...
    delete[] tmp;
    //...
}
```

But I was just moving the issue one step further, and in the process creating yet another array.
Unsurprisingly (although not really) memory consumption skyrocketed.

Questions here are:

- How do I solve this?
- Why did memory consumption lowered with the first change?

I don't really want to use `std::vector` because rewriting all the pertinent code seems like a major task, and because, as a rookie, I kind of feel better knowing that I did not need a library's help to write my program (obviously I still use them; I can't imagine what goes into writing something like `<iostream>` for example).

PS: My code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Jhonyrod/Dice/tree/master).

PPS: I apologize for my english; not a native speaker.

Comment: If you allocate memory with `new` you free it with `delete`, and if you allocate with `new[]` then free with `delete[]` (and if you have some old C function that allocates with `malloc` or `calloc`, then use `free`). When and where the allocation happens doesn't matter.

Comment: There is also a simpler solution to your problem, that will make the whole issue moot: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Whenever you think "dynamic array" or "runtime allocated array" or something similar, you should next always think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I might use `std::vector`, in fact I use it already because the program itself calculates the size of certain arrays, and using the native ones instead would make me run a whole bunch of code twice; first to calculate the size and then to fill in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What is the correct way to do this?
```

You should pair `new T[]` with `delete[]` - no magic here. To make sure you do it right use `std:unique_ptr<T[]>` - version for arrays. Or - std::vector, but you said you dont like it.

```
Why did memory consumption lowered with the first change?
```

seems ilogical, you allocated more memory and it dropped....

I took a look at your github project and I found [this](https://github.com/Jhonyrod/Dice/blob/master/Dice/PICompare.hpp):

```
delete[] slhs, srhs;                //Deletes the now useless sorted arrays.
```

delete[] does not list delete arrays, as far as I remember only srhs will get freed. You should write:

```
delete[] srhs;
delete[] slhs;
```

find other places like this, or use `std::unique_ptr<>`

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this as soon as I have some time to learn about those smart pointers. I'll update when I'm done with the modifications.

Comment: So I tried both; using `unique_ptr` and finding instances where `delete[]` was called with a list. Aparently I have the lowest memory consumption with `unique_ptr`, however, now performance plummeted, it takes several times more to run the program with the same parameters.